# (SQL) How can I put the count() into a column that already exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

In the next code I show the alias for count() as "coin" but I want to put it into the column named "matches" in the results, I hope somebody can help me please.

**the new column "matches' already exists in the table "candidates" and I want to fill it with count() values**

SQL code:

```
SELECT table1.* , count(*) as coin from (
(SELECT c.* from jobweb.candidates c, jobweb.additional_knowledge ak where
(ak.candidate_id = c.candidate_id) and (ak.knowledge like '%ccna%' or 
ak.knowledge_description like '%ccna%' or 
ak.knowledge like '%java%' or ak.knowledge_description like '%java%'))
union all
(SELECT c.* from jobweb.candidates c , jobweb.work_experience we where 
( we.candidate_id = c.candidate_id ) and
( we.position_name like '%sdh%' or we.functions_desciption like '%sdh%' or 
we.position_name like '%sharepoint%' or we.functions_desciption like '%sharepoint%' or 
we.position_name like '%proyecto%' or we.functions_desciption like '%proyecto%' or 
we.position_name like '%ingeniero%' or we.functions_desciption like '%ingeniero%' ))
union all
(SELECT c.* from jobweb.candidates c, jobweb.formal_education fe where
(fe.candidate_id =  c.candidate_id and fe.education_description like '%ingeniero%'))
)  as table1 group by table1.candidate_id order by coin desc
```

**SOLUTION:**
I discard to use SQL to extract the values on the column "matches" so I used hibernate to do that:

```
public List<Candidate> getCandidatesMatchesNativeSQL(String customQuery) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(customQuery)
            .addEntity(Candidate.class)
            .addScalar("matchCounter");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> objects = query.list();
    List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
    for (Object[] object : objects ) {
        Candidate candidate = (Candidate) object[0];
        BigInteger match = (BigInteger) object[1];
        candidate.setMatches( match.intValue() );
        candidates.add(candidate);
    }
    return candidates;
}
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Firebird? Oracle?

Comment: I'm Sorry I forgot it, is MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Just changed coin  to matches in select and order by.

```
       CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS 
   (SELECT table1.candidate_id , count(*) as coin   from (
    (SELECT c.* from jobweb.candidates c, jobweb.additional_knowledge ak where
    (ak.candidate_id = c.candidate_id) and (ak.knowledge like '%ccna%' or 
    ak.knowledge_description like '%ccna%' or 
    ak.knowledge like '%java%' or ak.knowledge_description like '%java%'))
    union all
    (SELECT c.* from jobweb.candidates c , jobweb.work_experience we where 
    ( we.candidate_id = c.candidate_id ) and
    ( we.position_name like '%sdh%' or we.functions_desciption like '%sdh%' or 
    we.position_name like '%sharepoint%' or we.functions_desciption like '%sharepoint%' or 
    we.position_name like '%proyecto%' or we.functions_desciption like '%proyecto%' or 
    we.position_name like '%ingeniero%' or we.functions_desciption like '%ingeniero%' ))
    union all
    (SELECT c.* from jobweb.candidates c, jobweb.formal_education fe where
    (fe.candidate_id =  c.candidate_id and fe.education_description like '%ingeniero%'))
    )  as table1 group by table1.candidate_id order by coin desc)

    Update A set A.matches=B.coin from 
    candidates A inner join table2 B on A.candidate_id=B.candidate_id
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was not very explicit, the new column "matches' already exists in the table "candidates" and I want to fill it with count() values

Comment: @DavilaR Check this above query and let me know this is working or not.here update query should be your matches column table

Comment: @Raja: A short explanation would help, your answer looks like "just edited the alias in the select". ;-) The simple magic is the UPDATE statement, the bigger magic is the "into #TEMP" (which was new for me, thx).

Comment: I tried but response this: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select c.* from jobweb.candidates c, jobweb.additional_knowledge ak where (ak.c' at line 2

Comment: @RajaRajendraprasath I don't know if the sintaxis #Temp is ok beacause it makes gray color the all sentences after #Temp

Comment: @RajaRajendraprasath yes, is MySQL, I checked with the new query but response other error: Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.